# How can I use read_csv for each csv files even if it is empty ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this piece of code to try to execute this program for each csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

directory_path_csv = r'CSV_Files'

for file in os.listdir(directory_path_csv):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        filename = file
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols= ['date','time', 'toto','tata'], parse_dates=[['date', 'time']])
```

But I have this error: **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File File1.csv does not exist: 'File.csv'** and don't understand why ? In the csv folder, I can have csv file with no data just the column's names.

Thanks for your time !

Comment: Your `file` is in the folder `directory_path_csv` so you need to do `os.path.join(directory_path_csv, file)`

Comment: @JustinEzequiel I can read the csv files, but when the program execute a certain one with just one line (columns names) since it cannot do the rest, the program stops without do the rest

Comment: Your error message (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File File1.csv does not exist: 'File.csv') does not match your claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# necessary imports
import pandas as pd
import glob
```

---

Lets say you have some non-empty csvs:

```
for x in range(10):
    pd.DataFrame(['exampleDf'+repr(x)]).to_csv('nonempty'+repr(x)+'.csv')
```

and an empty one:

```
# this is a shell command:
touch empty.csv
```

Put all csv filenames to a list

```
csvs=glob.glob('*csv')
```

You can loop through them catching [EmptyDataErrors](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.errors.EmptyDataError.html):

```
for csv in csvs:
    try:
        pd.read_csv(csv)
    except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
        pass # or do whatever you want with empty csvs
```

---

### EDIT: if csv has header but no data

If some csvs have headers but no data, some has data as well. Recreate situation:

```
for x in range(10):
    pd.DataFrame({'header':[1,2]}).to_csv('nonempty'+repr(x)+'.csv')
for x in range(10):
    pd.DataFrame({'header':[]}).to_csv('empty'+repr(x)+'.csv')
```

Then can do:

```
csvs=glob.glob('*csv')
for csv in csvs:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    if len(df.index)>0:
        # then df is non-empty, do whatever with it
        print(df)
    else:
        # then df is empty
        print(df)
```

Comment: thanks, I put `read_csv` et my treatments in the section `try` but when the program read another csv file, the first line is the name of the column of my df so it passed in the section `try` not in the `except` section

Comment: So your csv is not entirely empty, it has column names, but no data?

Comment: exactly ! Sorry for the misunderstanding